# Expression Engine template variable passing

Tags: expressionengine

I'm building in Expression Engine 2.3 a user profile system using Solspace's User and Friends modules. They work fine, but I'm having an incredibly difficult time with passing embedded variables around.

I've got a `.profile_head` template that's called from each template. The profile page, the friends page, the private messaging page, etc. It builds a user navigation, displays the avatar, all the common user stuff. All of this is based off of the user ID passed through `{segment_3}`. This allows me to display a different user's info by changing this segment.

The problem is doing this makes my URLs far too precise. I can't have users going to /users, they have to go to /users/profile/UID or the best possible scenario is an error page or redirect to the home page.

I tried to solve this problem through variables in my template:

```
{embed="/users/.profile_head" uid="{segment_3}"}
 or......
{embed="/users/.profile_head" uid="{logged_in_member_id}"}
```

In the `.profile_head` template file, I can print out `{embed:uid}` just fine, but when I try to assign it to anything (i.e. a loop or another template), it breaks:

```
<!-- /users/.profile_head -->
{exp:friends:members member_id="{embed:uid}" dynamic="off" limit="1"}
 or.....
{embed="users/.profile_column" uid="{embed:uid}"}
```

For instance, if `{embed:uid}` is set as `{logged_in_member_id}`, I get the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER in /var/www/system/expressionengine/libraries/Functions.php(656) : eval()'d code on line 9
```

This is line 9:

```
{if logged_in_member_id == "{embed:uid}"} <span class="this_is_you">This is you!</span>{/if}
```

I really am at my wits end. I need to be able to use this profile header in templates without requiring a user id in the URL for things like the user messaging and settings pages. But nothing I try seems to be working in the least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that `{logged_in_member_id}` is a *late-parsed variable*, which means it may not be available in some of your tags at the point they're processed - hence it's passed as literally `{logged_in_member_id}`.

Try using the `CURRENT_USER` constant instead.

Comment: That works. One more question though... In my embedded template, I've got this: `<a href="{site_url}users/sendmessage/{embed:uid}" class="bt_orange short">Send a Message</a>`. The URI gets evaluated to  `http://mysite.com/users/sendmessage/CURRENT_USER`. Is there any way to print the real user ID there? I assume `CURRENT_USER` is meant for use in tags and conditionals rather than printing, correct?

Comment: You can probably use `{logged_in_member_id}` in that situation, as it's not be evaluated, just being printed. Without seeing the complete hierarchy of embeds and conditionals it's hard to give a definitive answer on what should be used where. It can get tricky.

Comment: Problem is, the only reference the template can have for which user ID to use is what it's getting via `{embed:uid}`. If that embed var is `CURRENT_USER`, then that's what I've got to work with. I can't use `{logged_in_member_id}`, because I have to use the same template on pages that are referring to a user other than the one currently logged in.

Comment: But `CURRENT_USER` and `{logged_in_member_id}` are the same thing - it's just that one is parsed early and one is parsed late.

Comment: I understand that much. Let me try to explain it a little better. `mysite.com/users/profile`. No segment_3, so use current user. {embed="users/.profile_head" uid="CURRENT_USER"}. OR: `mysite.com/users/profile/4`. Segment 3, so use user 4. {embed="users/.profile_head" uid="{segment_3}"}.

Now, when I echo `{embed:uid}` in .profile_head, if I used `{segment_3}`, I get `4`. If I used `CURRENT_USER`, I get `CURRENT_USER`. That's the problem. I don't have any way to get the parsed ID if I'm using the constant in plain text (outside a conditional) in an embedded template.

Comment: According to the Solspace docs: "You can hardcode a member ID, pass it through an embed, grab it from the URI, or specify "CURRENT_USER" to display the profile of the currently logged in user." It looks like giving the actual string "CURRENT_USER" to the tag will produce the result you want.

Comment: Thanks Doug. I was able to work it out using conditionals in the end. Really appreciate all the help you guys have given.